# How to get separate dictionary of each record from list of dictionaries without using multiple loop?

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

In current data `"children"` key will be fix. If there is any child data available then there then it must in **list of dictionary format**.

If there is no any children available then it no `"children"` key is available in dictionary.

> **I don't want to use the loop to bifurcate this data.** 
>   *I want the same consistent sequence data. Please note there will any number of hierarchy available.*

I want all this data in **list of dictionary format** like given requirement data example.

**Current data.**

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "0",
    "is_active": true,
    "position": 1,
    "level": 1,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "name": "01",
            "is_active": false,
            "position": 1,
            "level": 2,
            "children": [
                "id": 9,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "010",
                "is_active": false,
                "position": 1,
                "level": 2,
                "children": [
                    <'Here N number of hirerchy availabe'>
                ]
            ]
        },

    ],
    "id": 3,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "1",
    "is_active": true,
    "position": 1,
    "level": 1,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "parent_id": 1,
            "name": "03",
            "is_active": false,
            "position": 1,
            "level": 2,
            "children": [
                "id": 6,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "030",
                "is_active": false,
                "position": 1,
                "level": 2,
                "children": [
                    <'Here N number of hirerchy availabe'>
                ]
            ]
        },

    ]
}
```

**Requirement.**

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "0",
    "is_active": true,
    "position": 1,
    "level": 1,
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "01",
    "is_active": false,
    "position": 1,
    "level": 2,
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "parent_id": 1,
    "name": "01",
    "is_active": false,
    "position": 1,
    "level": 2,
},{
    <N Number of dictionary data with consistant sequence>
}]
```

The suitable answer will definitely acceptable.

Comment: I feel recursion does the job. try it.

Comment: I have got my solution. I am going to answer my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flatten the given nested data structure with a recursive function like this:

```
def flatten(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return [data, *flatten(data.pop('children', ()))]
    return [subrecord for record in data for subrecord in flatten(record)]
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/BlankHatefulResources

Comment: Thanks man. I have already done. But your code is optimized. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution to my question. Below code is working for me.

```
if isinstance(categories, dict):
    values = {
        'name': categories.get('name'),
        'parent_id': categories.get('parent_id'),
        'magento_id': categories.get('id'),
        'instance_id': instance.id
    }
    self.category_list.append(values)
    self._analyse_response_data(categories.get('children_data'), instance)
if isinstance(categories, list):
    for category in categories:
        values = {
            'name': category.get('name'),
            'parent_id': category.get('parent_id'),
            'magento_id': category.get('id'),
            'instance_id': instance.id
        }
        self.category_list.append(values)
        self._analyse_response_data(category.get('children_data'), instance)
return self.category_list
```

I have used recursion to fulfil my requirement.

Comment: how exactly `for category in categories:` fit in the requirement `not using loop`? Not to mention that sample data is inconsistent. children should be list of dictionaries and that's not the case... Nevermind...

Comment: Hello @buran, Because it was as a child loop in recursion. Not as a parent.

Comment: The input and output of this answer differ significantly from those in the question.